# Send data to mongodb

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I have a file in jade:

```
img.profileImg(src="{{ identity.currentUser.profilePic }}")
.profileData {{ identity.currentUser.firstName }}
textarea#post-form.form-control(ng-model='activity.body')
button#post-btn.btn(ng-click="addpost(activity, identity.currentUser.profilePic,identity.currentUser.firstName,identity.currentUser.lastName)") Link
```

This is my addpost functoin:

```
addpost: function(activity){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var activity = new ActivityResource(activity);
            activity.profilePic = profilePic;
            activity.firstName = firstName;
            activity.lastName = lastName;

            activity.$save().then(function(){
                deferred.resolve();
            }, function(response){
                deferred.reject(response);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

activity.body is saved to mongodb but the rest of them (firstName, lastName , profilePic) wre not saved to the database, any suggestions? My skype is svetla_venci1 , I really need this emergency. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll need an AJAX call to your server and then a function to insert the data into your DB

Comment: The data is already saved , I save the activity.body but I want to save the identity.currentUser._id as activity.userId , how can I do that ?

Comment: Pass the ID back to the server and add it to the object being inserted

Comment: Add a parameter to your `addpost` function that takes the ID...

Comment: Can you please see my addpost function ?

Comment: I really need some help here , I would be really thankful if you help me because my deadline is tomorrow . Thanks in advance tymeJV

Comment: Give the answer I just posted a whirl - should work out

Comment: I did what you did there and I didn't work, it only saves everything from ng-model but when I pass identity.currentUser.firstName and take it with the functuin, I set post.firstName = firstName (firstName is the name I use to get the passed variable) and nothing happens but assigns the default value. My skype is svetla_venci1 , if you could add me I will be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

-Add your ID to the call in the view

```
button#post-btn.btn(ng-click="addpost(activity, identity.currentUser._id)") Link
```

-In your method:

```
addpost: function(activity, id){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var activity = new ActivityResource(activity);
        activity.userId = id;

        activity.$save().then(function(){
            deferred.resolve();
        }, function(response){
            deferred.reject(response);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```